# Subversion is installed and set, but fail to connect

Tags: linux, svn, centos

I aim to get my own SVN server.

I installed Subversion, all had been ok. I configured it

```
<Location /myrepo>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /svn/my_repo #edit:SVNParentPath /svn/my_repo


        #For any else operations, require an authenticated user.
        # Limit write permission to list of valid users.

        <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
              # Require SSL connection for password protection.
              # SSLRequireSSL

              AuthType Basic
              AuthName "Authorization Realm"
              AuthUserFile /etc/svn-users
              Require valid-user
        </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

And finally I ran `svnserver`:

```
svnserver -d
```

But... http://example.com/myrepo display 404, and Tortoise, SmartSVN and so third say:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://usertest@example.com/myrepo'
The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: no element found (http://usertest@example.com/myrepo)
```

Is this a matter of port or security options?

Comment: You should understand the difference of `SVNParentPath` and `SVNPath` first, then you could easily solve the issue. Make sure to read SVNBook: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.ref.mod_dav_svn

Comment: I am on SVNParentPath VS SVNPath. But it seems to not solve the deal, anyone I use. Much thks for pointing SVNBook.

Comment: Shouldnt I manage a VirtualHost for it ? => http://djlab.com/2011/04/subversion-subversion-cpanel-whm/

Comment: Ok, I leave it. Using GitHub lulz

Comment: If you can't configure Subversion yourself from the scratch by some reason you could install a pre-configured server.